# How to create a tooltip with external info

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a project I've been working on, I want to have tooltips (or any mouseover event that displays as a tooltip) with info that is gathered from elsewhere. I tried first to load some XML date but to no avail (XML isn't supposed to be used for this, I learned). Recently though, I discovered a website, with exactly the thing I was searching! So I went in the source files and tried to figure out how they did it, but since its a wiki website, there were too many scripts, and I cannot seem to figure it out. Here's what I'm talking about; the website http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions has a table with different "champions" (game-content, not important). If you hover over the first one for example ("Aatrox"), a tooltip displays with info that is clearly not written solely for that specific page. The info is gathered from somewhere else, and the tooltip itself is, as you can see, styled. I would be happy out of my mind, if I could just know the basics of how they did this. Where does the info come from? what kind of element is this "tooltip"? Can I do something like this with vanilla JS? If anyone could give me some pointers to get me going I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics of how this works:

1. Create database that contains the data
2. On hover, `GET` request to script to pull the data
3. Display the data in a styled `tooltip` or similar

If you watch the console when you hover over their table, you can see the `GET` request fire via `ajax` which loads the data.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I suppose it's a PHP database then. Sorry 'bout the vague question, but thanks for helping me instead of simply downvoting it. Very much appreciated!